# Strange behavior when sending mails with PEAR with authentication

Tags: php, pear, cpanel, whm, smtp-auth

I am trying to use PHP PEAR to send 50,000 individual emails using SMTP authentication. Everything works fine in my tests (10 to 20 mails) but when I run the real script, it starts sending fine but after some time, the response is weird:

```
user@domain.com -  authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 435, response: Unable to authenticate at present)]
user2@domain2.com - Failed to set sender: bounces@mydomain.com [SMTP: Failed to write to socket: unknown error (code: -1, response: )]
user3@domain3.com -  authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: TLS go ahead)]
user4@domian4.com - Failed to set sender: bounces@mydomain.com [SMTP: Failed to write to socket: unknown error (code: -1, response: �0Ï¡;d´áCYB
Ø#ÔÒñ¿ªÊ5Áð%‹_éW’•:ºŸ,jw…�åô4Ì«á9}SE� *ÄùÌ1#.=6÷N€%¬-Yaˆ:#iÈ9åþO´Ðˆ£âwSE�Pƒâ^@è0jÉE$aŸcEâù
```

I know that the email addresses are valid, and it doesn't fail in the same one each time, and also has nothing to do with the time the script has been running, it runs for 20 hours and doesn't stop, it is confirmed. An email is sent every 0.74 seconds. In whm I have no limit in sending mails per hour nor incoming smtp connections, only outgoing simultaneous smtp connections, but that has nothing to do because they are in the queue, right?

I have also checked the server resources and the proccess is only using 13% of ram and the cpu is between 15% and 25%, so I don't know where else to check. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there any firewalls to stop Spaming on your server ?

Comment: I only have spamassasin installed.

Comment: Ask your host support for that. And in your tests, log everything to see what exactly happens. Maybe there is sth wrong in your code!

Comment: Abadis, thank you. I review my code and everything is fine, in fact, it is a While condition, so the code is the same, it is weird that it works for X number of emails and suddenly it stops working. I don´t receive any spam filter activated or else, and also I checked with my host, which is hostv, and said that there is no limitation.